# Слева картинка, справа текст со свойствами td

Tags: html, css

Уважаемые коллеги, помогите разрешить проблему:

```
<style>
    .imgWrap {
        margin:0px 8px 0px 0px;
        float:left;
    }
    .txtWrap {
        float:left;
    }
</style>
<div>
    <div class="imgWrap"><img src="someimage.jpg" alt=""/></div>
    <div class="txtWrap">любой текст любой текст любой текст любой текст любой текст</div>
</div>
```

Каким образом можно добиться переноса текста в `div class="txtWrap"`, а не переноса этого `div` под картинку? Ширину картинки мы не знаем, соответственно задать ширину `div` с текстом тоже не можем. Отсюда собственно и проблема.

p.s. текст не должен обтекать картинку, div элемент с текстом должен вести себя подобно `<td>картинка</td><td>текст</td>`.

Заранее спасибо. Очень жду решения.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
    .imgWrap {    
        margin:0px 8px 0px 0px;    
        float:left;
    }    
    .txtWrap {    
        /*убрать*/
        /*float:left;*/
        display:table-cell;
    }
</style>
<div>
    <div class="imgWrap">
        <img src="someimage.jpg" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="txtWrap">любой текст любой текст любой текст любой текст любой текст
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: В этом случае текст будет обтекать картинку, а это не удовлетворяет решению задачи.

Comment: Тогда остается только заюзать таблицы, либо задать соответвующую высоту для .imgWrap, либо использовать js.

Comment: Знаю, что это делается средствами CSS, но не могу найти решение в сети, хотя ранее где-то встречал. Подождём, что скажут другие.

Comment: Признаю был неправ )

    .txtWrap{
        display:table-cell;
    }

Comment: Странно, что так просто. Нужно протестировать на кросбраузерность. В любом случае большое спасибо!

Comment: Действительно для кросбраузерности этого недостаточно, необходимо добавить в .txtWrap height:100%, проверено в IE6,7,8,9, Chrome, Opera, FF.